# Why does Ubuntu use old Evolution?

Tags: evolution

In Maverick, most of the Gnome software are version 2.32, but Evolution is version 2.30.3. Lucid also used an older version of Evolution. I think Evolution is getting better and better and makes sense to ship a newer version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New software needs testing before it can be pulled into a distribution and 2.32.0 was only released right at the end of September, not giving it anywhere near enough time for testing.

Stability is all the more important in a mission-critical applications like Evolution, Firefox and OpenOffice.

This is just how things go sometimes.

Comment: Doesn't Evolution follow the same release schedule as other Gnome applications such as Empathy and Gwibber which are version 2.32?

Comment: Yes. Gnome 2.32 wasn't released until Evolution 2.32 was released. However parts of Gnome were ready before the whole thing was so they got pulled in.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that Ubuntu releases should have more time to pull in the upstream Gnome releases? Aka longer between Gnome and Ubuntu releases?

Comment: @danne Yes but it depends when the release is. For example, Gnome 3.0 isn't due until the beginning of April. Ubuntu developers don't think that's enough time to get everything ready so all the Gnome 3 things are being pushed off to a PPA for inclusion in 11.10.